# Совет учредителей ВАДА - слово "совет" с прописной?

Tags: прописная-строчная, названия, прописная, строчная

С прописной или строчной слово "совет" в следующем названии: **совет учредителей ВАДА**?

С учетом того, что это главный орган Всемирного антидопингового агентства.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выбор прописной или строчной буквы не зависит от статуса наименования.
Все зависит от того, входит ли слово "совет" в официальное наименование или нет. Если слово "совет" входит в официальное наименование, выбор прописной буквы уместен.

Правила таковы:

**С ПРОПИСНОЙ БУКВЫ пишется:**

1.Первое слово полного официального названия и входящие в его состав собственные имена:

> международных и российских высших органов власти, иных государственных органов:
>   Государственная дума, Федеральное собрание Российской Федерации, Конституционный суд, Генеральная прокуратура России, Государственный **совет,** Высший арбитражный суд Российской Федерации, Генеральная прокуратура Российской Федерации, Администрация Президента Российской Федерации, Верхняя палата Государственной думы, **Совет** по аграрной политике при Правительстве Российской Федерации, **Консультационный совет по иностранным инвестициям в России, Экспертный совет при Правительстве Российской Федерации,** Комиссия Правительства Российской Федерации по оперативным вопросам, Международный валютный фонд и т.д.
>
> Примечание: **Ранее в названиях высших государственных учреждений все слова писались с прописной буквы**. *В настоящее время по традиции с прописной буквы пишутся все слова в следующих названиях: Организация Объединенных Наций, Совет Безопасности, Общество Красного Креста и Красного Полумесяца*